# How to delete logs in IBM Containers service (BlueMix)

Tags: logging, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have multiple dockers for some applications running on IBM Containers service.

When I execute:

```
cf ic logs -f CONTAINER_NAME
```

I see logs for that container but I don't know where that logs are cached.

For example, in the case of a Websphere Liberty profile container if I enter the container and remove the Liberty messages.log and trace.log in /logs directory, I execute previous command and I still see past logs, so that means that the container service is somehow keeping old logs and not reading them directly from the running image.

How can I reset/remove the logs so cf ic logs command is cleaned and does not show very old log content not relevant anymore?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `cf ic logs` command is basically the `docker logs` command against the Bluemix containers service, and (by default, unless modified) shows the stdout/stderr of the main process in the container.  They're not stored inside the container, but rather as metadata against it.

The docker daemon does not appear to support a `docker logs clear` type command at this time, and most of the references I can find effectively resolve down to either a) recreate the container (new container = new logs) or b) go onto the host as root and force truncate/remove the open log files as root (not really an option here).

Comment: Thanks. So in this case, "host" means BlueMix service, right? Not my running container... because I can delete the logs in my container but that does not deletes them in the IBM Container service. (Just wanted to be sure I got it)

Comment: Correct, which is why it's not really an option here - I was mostly being complete about the docker daemon behavior itself.  Sorry for the confusion.  Only real option in this case is to recreate the container.  A bit like killing an ant with a sledgehammer, though.